# Rails debugging error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to debug a project in Rails.However,I constantly get this error in the browser:undefined local variable or method `byebug' for #"<"ArticlesController:0x9430c68>.
The code for the Articles Controller is:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article,only: [:edit,:update,:show,:destroy]
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    byebug
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    #@article.user = User.first
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article was succesfully created."
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update

    if @article.update(article_params)
      flash[:success] = "Article was succesfully updated."
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def destroy

    @article.destroy
    flash[:danger]="Article was succesfully deleted."
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article =  Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title,:description)
    end
end
```

The error appears logically on the byebug command in the 'create' action.The gem 'byebug' is installed in the Gemfile:

```
 group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3'
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger 
   console
   gem 'byebug', platform: :mri

 end
```

I work in Rails 5,and my IDE is Atom.I have searched and tried multiple answers,none of which have worked,so I have returned everything to how it was.Thank you for taking time to solve this problem,it means a lot!

Comment: Are you running on MRI, or some other platform like JRuby?

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, try changing

```
gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
```

to

```
gem 'byebug', platform: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
```

Otherwise, since people seem to have a lot of problems using byebug with Windows, I would try using a different debugger like `pry`.

With Rails you want to add the `pry-rails gem` into your Gemfile then run `bundle install`.

Comment: I tried it,still didn't work-the computer doesn't recognise byebug in the require line("cannot load such file --byebug").

Comment: Hmm...I know a lot of people have issues using byebug with Windows.  I edited my answer and suggest looking into the pry debugger gem.

Comment: Installed pry.Still getting a similar error,except this time it is for pry("cannot load such file --pry") at the line "require 'pry'".I tired to move it above the Controller class,but the same error shows up.Pry is installed without a doubt,I checked via Git Bash.Do you have any other debugging gems to suggest?

Comment: hmm..  Did you use the `pry-rails gem`?  You should have something like `gem 'pry-rails', group: [:development, :test]` in your Gemfile.

Comment: Finally!The pry-rails gem works perfectly!Thank you so very much.

Comment: awesome... glad to help.